# QGIS Map Composer, right hand pane has gone!

Tags: qgis

in the QGIS map composer, I accidentally closed the right hand pane, the pane that includes the command history, item properties, etc. Now I can't get them back. There are no icons to click to get them back, nothing. If I close QGIS and reopen, the pane is still gone.

What do I do to get the pane back?

Comment: @NathanW Yup, you're right, that's the exact problem. Thanks for spotting it, I did search but not with the right terms apparently.

Comment: All good.  It's been fixed in 2.0.